# Python gzip and Java GZIPOutputStream give different results

Tags: java, python, gzip, gzipoutputstream

I'm trying to take hash of gzipped string in Python and need it to be identical to Java's. But Python's `gzip` implementation seems to be different from Java's `GZIPOutputStream`.

Python `gzip`:

```
import gzip
import hashlib

gzip_bytes = gzip.compress(bytes('test', 'utf-8'))
gzip_hex = gzip_bytes.hex().upper()
md5 = hashlib.md5(gzip_bytes).hexdigest().upper()

>>>gzip_hex
'1F8B0800678B186002FF2B492D2E01000C7E7FD804000000'
>>>md5
'C4C763E9A0143D36F52306CF4CCC84B8'
```

Java `GZIPOutputStream`:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class HelloWorld{
    private static final char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
    
    public static String md5(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytes);
            return bytesToHex(thedigest);
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            new RuntimeException("MD5 Failed", e);
        }
        return new String();
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
         String string = "test";
         final byte[] bytes = string.getBytes();
         try {
             final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             final GZIPOutputStream gout = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
             gout.write(bytes);
             gout.close();
             final byte[] encoded = bos.toByteArray();
             System.out.println("gzip: " + bytesToHex(encoded));
             System.out.println("md5: " + md5(encoded));
         }
         catch(IOException e)  {
             new RuntimeException("Failed", e);
         }
     }
}
```

Prints:

```
gzip: 1F8B08000000000000002B492D2E01000C7E7FD804000000
md5: 1ED3B12D0249E2565B01B146026C389D
```

So, both gzip bytes outputs seem to be very similar, but slightly different.

1F8B0800**678B186002FF**2B492D2E01000C7E7FD804000000

1F8B0800**000000000000**2B492D2E01000C7E7FD804000000

Python `gzip.compress()` method accepts `compresslevel` argument in range of 0-9. Tried all of them, but none gives desired result.
Any way to get same result as Java's `GZIPOutputStream` in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement "hash of gzipped string in Python and need it to be identical to Java's" cannot be met in general. You need to change your requirement, implementing your need differently. I would recommend requiring simply that the *decompressed* data have identical hashes. In fact, there is a 32-bit hash (a CRC-32) of the decompressed data already there in the two gzip strings, which are identical (`0xd87f7e0c`). If you want a longer hash, then you can append one. The last four bytes is the uncompressed length, modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, so you can compare those as well. Just compare the last eight bytes of the two strings and check that they are the same.

The difference between the two gzip strings in your question illustrates the issue. One has a time stamp in the header, and the other does not (set to zeros). Even if they both had time stamps, they would still very likely be different. They also have some other bytes in the header different, like the originating operating system.

Furthermore, the compressed data in your examples is extremely short, so it just so happens to be identical in this case. However for any reasonable amount of data, the compressed data generated by two gzippers will be different, *unless* they happen to made with exactly the same deflate code, the same version of that code, and the same memory size and compression level settings. If you are not in control of all of those, you will never be able to assure the same compressed data coming out of them, given identical uncompressed data.

In short, don't waste your time trying to get identical compressed strings.

Comment: I tried to to simply replace that "header timestamp" with 00, like:
`data = data[:8] + '000000000000' + data[20:]`
And tested it on different large amount of data. Looks like that helped. Results are same now.

Comment: You're not listening.

Comment: That java code returned same results on Android arm and windows x64.
I dont think there are some "operating system" bytes there.
And even if there were some - I would also prefer to remove them. The point here is emulate original android behaviour.

Comment: Still not listening.